# Rewrite Sharepoint URL (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: 2013

I'd like to rewrite all my site urls in the way the the user can't figure out the exact name of the the page his viewing.
let's say that my site is "www.justarandomsite.com"  and may page is "page.aspx"
I' like to have instead of "www.justarandomsite.com/pages/page.aspx" sothing like this:
"www.justarandomsite.com/skdhfjksdgfjksdgfjdsgvdjhsgfjdsdsjfgkdsjgfkdsgfjdsgfjkdsg"

Answer (score 2):

Managed navigation will allow you to do this.

This blog details how to enable it. Then you can make the paths to your pages anything you want.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/justinvoels/archive/2012/12/05/sharepoint-managed-navigation-part-1.aspx

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it, can you clarify a bit. I changed my post a little.